# SELECT THAT ALSO SET TO VARIABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just got a job to a company to maintain an existing program in the company.

Now I need to get a data from table.

So I need to do a select from a table, the table column dateBegin maybe null maybe not, so if datebegin is null i get the datebegin2. and dateto is added 1 year from the datebegin if is null or <= datebegin.

All I can do now is using case when else to get the right value. But its too long for the code and hard to read. How can I achieve the code right below? thanks for your response...

```
declare @val smalldatetime

select id
     , @val = COALESCE(dateBegin, dateBegin2) as DateBegin
     , COALESCE(dateTo, dateadd(Y, 1, @val)) As DateTo 
from TblL
```

Comment: You can't do this. A `SELECT` statement can either output the resultset, or assign those values to variables. It cannot do both at the same time; as the error you would have got when you tried told you.

Comment: if that so. then its ok. thanks for your reply

Comment: You won't need a `CASE` try this
`select id COALESCE(dateTo, dateadd(Y, 1, COALESCE(dateBegin, dateBegin2))) As DateTo from TblL`

Comment: @Larnu, Sometimes I use `APPLY` to create *variables* on the fly... Very useful to avoid repeated complex expressions...

Comment: @BhavinGosai I think the OP needs the `DateBegin` in the query as well as the `DateTo` and did not want to repeat the code... This is not possible with a variable as attempted, but I suggest an approach with `APPLY` in my answer.

Comment: @Shnugo yes, i do similar things as well; especially with things like `CHARINDEX`  (as you have done in your example). It might help the OP reach their goal, however, my point still stands that you can't output and assign in the same statement. :)

Comment: @Larnu sure, this is correct 

Comment: Thanks all for the great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix this, but you can use `APPLY` to *row-wise* compute additional columns. These columns can be used within the statement similar to a variable:

Cannot test this, but this should be equivalent to your attempt:

```
select id
     , A.DateBegin
     , COALESCE(dateTo, dateadd(Y, 1, A.DateBegin)) As DateTo 
from TblL
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COALESCE(dateBegin, dateBegin2)) AS A(DateBegin)
```

A working example to illustrate the idea

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Find the #value# between the "#"')
                      ,('One more #example#');
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.SomeString 
      ,A.FirstHash
      ,B.SecondHash
      ,SUBSTRING(t.SomeString,A.FirstHash+1,C.FragmentLength) AS Fragment
FROM @tbl AS t      
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)) AS A(FirstHash)                  
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString,A.FirstHash+1)) AS B(SecondHash)          
CROSS APPLY(SELECT B.SecondHash-A.FirstHash-1) AS C(FragmentLength);
```

Returns

```
ID  SomeString                         1.#  2.# Fragment
1   Find the #value# between the "#"    10  16  value
2   One more #example#                  10  18  example
```

The same query without this trick would be something like this

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.SomeString 
      ,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)
      ,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)+1)
      ,SUBSTRING(t.SomeString,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)+1,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString,CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)+1)-CHARINDEX('#',t.SomeString)-1) AS Fragment
FROM @tbl AS t
```

Comment: This is what i wanted. Thanks for your answer. It really help me out